# Datagridview doesn't update

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, objectcontext

I work on windows form with entity framework 5.

I have a datagridview to record new sales and a save button to save changes on my entities.
But before saving the entities, I create some new stock objects. I have another gridview that looks at my stock but which is readonly.

My issues are the followings:

- The sales and stock are updated in my database but while the gridview for sales show the new sales, the gridview for stock doesn't update to show the new stock
- If there was an error on adding a new sale (say a foreign key error when inserting into the database) then after correcting the error and re-clicking on save, the sale is inserted once but the stock twice (or as many times as I had en error message)

I tried to create my stock through the createobject method rather than just with the new keywork but the problems remain.

Here is my saveButton click code

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var txnsGr = (IEnumerable<TransactionsGroupee>)this.achatsGroupeeBindingSource.DataSource;

            foreach (var txnGr in txnsGr)
                if (txnGr.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
                    ge.TransactionsGroupees.AddObject(txnGr);

            var localTransactions = ge.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Where(ent => ent.Entity is Transaction).Select(ent => ent.Entity as Transaction);
            var achats = localTransactions.Where(x => x.TransactionsGroupee.sens == (int)Sens.Achat);
            foreach (Transaction txn in achats)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < txn.quantite; i++)
                {
                    Stock stock = ge.CreateObject<Stock>();
                    stock.Agence1 = agence;
                    stock.Transaction = txn;
                    ge.Stocks.AddObject(stock);
                }
            }
            ge.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder(ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                err.AppendLine().Append(ex.InnerException.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Note that my sales (from two gridviews in a master/details configuration actually) where somehow detached and I have to attach them back first but hopefully this is not related to the issues described above.

Comment: For porblem 2, I decided to create a List<object> that contains all created entity outside the datagridview (As my stock for example) and in the catch of my save button, I delete all these objects from my context.

Comment: I discovered that the bindingsource of the gridview that shows the stock (which is a sql view) was ignored... Don't know why. So I directly used the datasource of the gridview rather than going through the bindingsource provided by the designer and now it works.